# Flickering headlight

Tags: headlight, lights

I own 2014 ford fusion SE with halogen (H7) headlights.

There is a weird issue with drivers side lamp - sometimes it randomly flickers a bit and because of this reason bulbs go out fast. Bumpy road doesn't increase the flickering, however, if I turn on turn signal then flickering intensifies and becomes very obvious.

Has anyone had this issue? The generator works fine and outputs stable voltage and passengers headlight works fine as well.﻿﻿ I have changed bulbs a few weeks ago.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a loose connection.

This could be either on the headlamp or at the ground or earth point for that headlamp.

There may be individual fuses for the headlamps and that one could have a loose connection.

Comment: A loose connection would tend to be more apparent on a bumpy road, wouldn't it?

Comment: @GdD just the vibration of the engine is sometimes sufficient...